# Callback was already called angular cli

Tags: webpack, angular-cli, angular5

I updated my angular-cli then i got error in ng serve

```
 Callback was already called.
at throwError (node_modules\neo-async\async.js:14:11)
at node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2805:7
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

and this is versions of my project packages:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.0.1

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.7
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.7
@angular/cdk                      5.2.4
@angular/cli                      6.0.7
@angular/material                 5.2.4
@angular/platform-server          5.1.1
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.7
@schematics/angular               0.6.7
@schematics/update                0.6.7
rxjs                              5.5.2
typescript                        2.4.2
webpack                           4.4.1
```

I tried to remove node-modules then re- npm install but still have the same error ... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem and found a solution thanks to this discussion:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6417

It seems to be a problem triggered when updating to Angular 6.

First run:

```
sudo npm ls webpack
```

If it returns more than one version of webpack, that's where your problem lies:

```
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.6.8
│ └── webpack@4.8.3 
└── webpack@4.17.1
```

Unless you have need for it elsewhere, you only need webpack to be in @angular-devkit/build-angular.

I'd also updated all of @angular-devkit/* with @latest.

Once it was clear there was more than one version, I did the following to get it working again:

```
sudo npm uninstall --save-dev webpack
sudo npm ls webpack
sudo npm cache verify
```

I had uninstalled @angular-devkit/build-angular in trying to find the solution. So I plugged that back in before doing anything else. It seems to have its own version of webpack with it. If you already have it there, just update it.

Note that I didn't reinstall webpack with `sudo npm i webpack`. It didn't like that no matter what way I tried it.

```
sudo npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest
sudo npm ls webpack
```

Once there was only one version of webpack, `ng serve` should work again with no errors.

P.S. An alternative fix suggested by peterpeterparker helped me find this solution. Please note that I haven't tried it, but thought it may be helpful.

[peterpeterparker's fix](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/581):

```
 npm remove webpack --save
 rm -r node_modules
 rm package-lock.json
 npm install
```

P.P.S. Sudo is only for mac. I added it for ease of copy & paste of my solution. Don't copy it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred because then compatible webpack version is higher then @angular-devkit/build-angular 
solution:- npm update @angular-devkit/build-angular --save-dev

let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

If removing webpack from your package.json doesn't work for you:

In my case I just needed to update the following dependencies : "@angular-devkit/core", "@angular-devkit/build-angular", and "@angular-devkit/schematics" to the following version : "0.8.1".

This way "@angular-devkit/build-angular" had the same version than the webpack specified in my package.json (4.18.0).

This means that if your run `npm ls webpack` and have multiple results, you don't have to remove webpack from your project, you just need both versions to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same message in the console after cloning someone else's repository and trying to run the code on localhost:4200. I solved the problem by enabling the correct version of node.js
I use nvm. You can enter in your console `nvm ls`, `nvm current`, and switch between versions.
I was using version 17 but I entered `nvm use 14` in the console to switch to this version because it was used in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when trying to add lazy load feature in Angular 8.

```
├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29
| └── webpack@4.39.2 
└── webpack@4.41.1
```

I tried to update @angular-devkit/build-angular to latest but was not working. Many new issues surfaced. When I removed webpack@4.41.1, the same problem 'cannot find module webpack'. So I tried to make the webpack versions same. Used 'npm install webpack@4.39.2'.
Finally the problem was solved. When I type 'npm ls webpack', only one webpack is shown and the build works fine.

```
`-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29
  `-- webpack@4.39.2
```