# Angular7 - Error while implementing lazy-loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular7

**I am getting below error while implementing lazy-loading using angular 7.
Whenever running command `ng serve` below error is populated on cmd.**

**20% building modules 91/93 modules 2 active ...Web\src\assets\bootstrap\bootstrap.scss× ｢wdm｣: Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
        at addDependency** (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:671:12)
        at iterationOfArrayCallback (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:186:3)
        at addDependenciesBlock (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:689:5)
        at iterationOfArrayCallback (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:186:3)
        at addDependenciesBlock (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:692:5)
        at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:700:4)
        at afterBuild (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:832:15)
        at buildModule.err (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:876:11)
        at callback (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:613:5)
        at module.build.error (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:653:12)
        at resolveDependencies (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:282:4)
        at ContextModule.result.resolveDependencies (E:\New folder\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:522:25)
        at ContextModule.build (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:203:8)
        at Compilation.buildModule (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:618:10)
        at factory.create (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:859:14)
        at hooks.afterResolve.callAsync (E:\New folder\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModuleFactory.js:163:16)
    E:\New folder\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:14
        throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
        ^

```
Error: Callback was already called.
    at throwError (E:\New folder\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:14:11)
    at E:\New folder\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2805:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

### app.routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
        { path: 'login', loadChildren: 'app/components/login/login.module#LoginModule'}   <--- causing error
]
```

However, using routing as below is below is working finr:-

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
    },
        { path: 'login', component:LoginComponent} <--- working  fine
]
```

### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
            "@angular/animations": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/common": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/core": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/forms": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/http": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/platform-server": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/pwa": "^0.10.6",
            "@angular/router": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/service-worker": "^7.0.3",
            "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
            "@types/lodash": "^4.14.116",
            "core-js": "^2.5.7",
            "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
            "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
            "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
            "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^6.3.1",
            "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.0",
            "ngx-ui-switch": "^1.6.0",
            "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
            "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
            "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
            "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.5",
            "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/cli": "^7.0.5",
            "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.3",
            "@angular/material": "^7.0.3",
            "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.11",
            "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
            "@types/node": "^10.12.6",
            "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
            "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
            "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
            "karma": "^3.1.1",
            "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
            "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
            "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
            "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
            "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
            "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
            "protractor": "^5.4.1",
            "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5",
            "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
            "tslint": "^5.11.0",
            "typescript": "^3.1.6",
            "webpack": "^4.20.2"
        }
```

### app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [
        HttpService,
        AuthGuard,
        WebsocketService
    ],
    entryComponents: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### login.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { loginRouting } from './login.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        loginRouting
    ],
    declarations: [LoginComponent]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

### login.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];

export const loginRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "types": [
        "node"
      ],
      "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
      ],
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "paths": {    
      },
      "module": "es2015"
    }
  }
```

### ng --version

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.1
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.1
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
... service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.7
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.7
@angular/pwa                      0.10.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.7
@schematics/angular               7.0.7
@schematics/update                0.11.1
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.27.0
```

Comment: please share your app.module.ts and login.module.ts file

Comment: @RezaRahmati, Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set routing file this way.

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
   { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
];
```

And make sure in `login.module.ts` you have set it's component

```
declarations: [LoginComponent]
```

**Update**

While you update from 6 to 7. This issue may happen. 
For that please read and follow this commands and steps.

[Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599606/callback-was-already-called-angular-cli)

Comment: @Mahi Have you upgrade angular version ?

Comment: Angular CLI: 7.1.1
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.1

Comment: @Mahi I mean have you install fresh angular version ? or update like angular 6 to angular 7 ?

Comment: Updated to angular7 from 6

Comment: For me,(1) npm ls webpack  (2) uninstalling webpack and @angular-devkit/build-angular (package.json) then (3) Installing @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest (4) npm install. ie remove webpack and update @angular-devkit/build-angular to latest works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50599606/callback-was-already-called-angular-cli   is useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong if your 'components' folder on the same level of app.routing.ts file, Then try this.

`const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './components/login/login.module#LoginModule'}

]`

Answer (score 0):

It's additional webpack issue in the package.json

1. npm ls webpack
2. if found two webpacks, removed one from package.json
3. npm install

More info - https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/583